# Appending checkboxes labels of a form into a <p> element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to do this for a few hours but couldn't succeed. So I decided to ask help here.

So, I have a form:

```
<form id="ecommerce-form">
   <input type="checkbox" id="seopremium" name="option-ecommerce" value="seopremium">
   <label for="seopremium" class="lead">SEO premium</label>
   <input type="checkbox" id="moyenpaiement" name="option-ecommerce" value="moyenpaiement">
   <label for="moyenpaiement" class="lead">Configuration paiements</label>
   <input type="checkbox" id="facturation" name="option-ecommerce" value="facturation">
   <label for="facturation" class="lead">Facturation simplifiée</label>
   <input type="checkbox" id="avisclients" name="option-ecommerce" value="avisclients">
   <label for="avisclients" class="lead">Avis clients</label>
   <input type="checkbox" id="additionnalsecurity" name="option-ecommerce" value="additionnalsecurity">
   <label for="additionnalsecurity" class="lead">Sécurité supplémentaire</label>
   <input type="checkbox" id="basketoptions" name="option-ecommerce" value="basketoptions">
   <label for="basketoptions" class="lead">Panier avec options</label>
</form>
```

And I'm trying to print the label's text of checkboxes that are checked automatically into a Paragraph:

```
<p class="recap-option"><strong>Options:</strong></p><p class="options-selected"></p>
```

So if everything is checked the Paragraph would be:

```
<p class="recap-option"><strong>Options:</strong></p><p class="options-selected">SEO premium, Configuration paiements, facturation simplifiée, Avis clients, Sécurité supplémentaire, Panier avec options</p>
```

Or in clear:

> **Options:** SEO premium, Configuration paiements, facturation simplifiée, Avis clients, Sécurité supplémentaire, Panier avec options

I found a few solutions here for problems that seemed relatively similar but I wasn't able to adapt the code for my own needs.

http://jsfiddle.net/5ryy9krn/2/

So the goal is simply appending what is between each  into the paragraph element.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Please include your code snippet on site in a [mcve], rather than only linking to an off site snippet tool

Comment: Also include the output you're trying to create

Comment: Is it better like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fetch the `label` element and use its value to append into the `selected-area`.

And on uncheck, also follow the same procedure to remove the unchecked element from the `selected-area`

You can define the `onChange` function in the following way to achieve the expected behavior.

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    var elements = $(this).parent('div');
    const checkedItem  = elements.find("label").text();
    $('#seleted-rows').append(`<p name="${checkedItem}">${checkedItem}</p>`);
  } else {
    var elements = $(this).parent('div');
    const uncheckedItem = elements.find("label").text();
    $('#seleted-rows').find(`p[name="${uncheckedItem}"]`).remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pb-5 devis-invisible" id="devis-ecommerce">
   <form id="ecommerce-form">
      <div class="row pb-5">
         <div class="col-4">
            <input type="checkbox" id="seopremium" name="option-ecommerce" value="seopremium">
            <label for="seopremium" class="lead">SEO premium</label>
         </div>
         <div class="col-4">
            <input type="checkbox" id="moyenpaiement" name="option-ecommerce" value="moyenpaiement">
            <label for="moyenpaiement" class="lead">Configuration paiements</label>
         </div>
         <div class="col-4">
            <input type="checkbox" id="facturation" name="option-ecommerce" value="facturation">
            <label for="facturation" class="lead">Facturation simplifiée</label>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-4">
            <input type="checkbox" id="avisclients" name="option-ecommerce" value="avisclients">
            <label for="avisclients" class="lead">Avis clients</label>
         </div>
         <div class="col-4">
            <input type="checkbox" id="additionnalsecurity" name="option-ecommerce" value="additionnalsecurity">
            <label for="additionnalsecurity" class="lead">Sécurité supplémentaire</label>
         </div>
         <div class="col-4">
            <input type="checkbox" id="basketoptions" name="option-ecommerce" value="basketoptions">
            <label for="basketoptions" class="lead">Panier avec options</label>
         </div>
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Selected Items</p>
  <div id="seleted-rows">

</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works fine! It was exactly what I was trying to achieve!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want something like this:

```
var labels = document.querySelectorAll("input:checked ~ label);
labels.foreach(function(label) {
  console.log(label.textContent);
});
```

It isn't clear to me which paragraph you want these labels added to, so I used console.log and left it for you to put the label.texContent into your paragraph(s)

Comment: Hello, I edited the main post. Let me know if it's still unclear, I'm going to try your solution in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

You have to gather all input[type=checkbox]:checked and the labels.

Using your example this could be done with:

```
var nodelistChecked = document.querySelectorAll("#ecommerce-form input[type=checkbox]:checked");
// nodelistChecked now contains a Node-list with all checked input elements
```

With this result you can gather the text from the labels with an Array.prototype.map function call. The result from a querySelectorAll()-call is a Nodelist and doesn't know forEach/map/or other Array-like function-calls, so you have to call it and convert it with map to an array.

```
var arrLabelText = 
  Array.prototype.map.call(nodelistChecked, function(node) {
    return (document.querySelector('label[for='+node.id+']')
      || document.createElement('label')).textContent;
  });
// arrLabelText contains an array with all selected labels 
// the || new element is used, to avoid errors if no label is found
```

After this you can display the value in the element you want to display it:

```
document.querySelector("p.options-selected").innerText = arrLabelText.join(', ');
```

When you use jQuery it is a a bit shorter and it avoids some error-checking (like no label found):

```
function fillSelectedOptions() {
  $("p.options-selected").text(
    Array.prototype.slice.call( // depending on the jQuery version, this might be required
      $("#ecommerce-form input[type=checkbox]:checked")
        .map(function(i,node) { /* jQuery returns the index first */
          return $('label[for="'+node.id+'"]').text()
        })
    ).join(', ')
  );
}
$("#ecommerce-form input[type=checkbox]").each(function(i, node) {
  $(node).on('change', fillSelectedOptions);
});
```